# NSIS copy subfolders and files in them to install dir

Tags: nsis

With this it will copy all files from **res** folder,

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"    
  File "res\"
```

but I need to copy all subfolders and files in them.
How can I achive that.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [manual](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#file) is very clear, use `File /r "yourfolder"` to copy the whole directory tree...